# permutations with recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I have a task to make a code that takes a list of undefined number and print all permutations with the first constant using recursion and here is a code I wrote but I don't know where is the problem

```
 portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]


def permutations(route, ports):
    for items in ports:
        route.append(ports)
        ports = ports[:items]+ports[items+1:]
        permutations(route, ports)
    print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in route]))


permutations([0], list(range(1, len(portnames))))
```

note: the function must contain

Comment: What is the problem? What happens, what should happen?

Comment: Is the problem the maximum recursion depth gets exceeded fir this simple problem?

Comment: generally speaking, if the recursion is large, then the code will get `stack overflow`. You can avoid this with loops, but in your case, for permutations, you can actually use the inbuilt `itertools` module.

Comment: A good reference to recursive code in Python with an explanation is: [Generate Permutations in Python Recursively From Scratch](https://python.plainenglish.io/generating-permutations-in-python-recursively-from-scratch-c3cc2285e9e6)

Comment: @DarrylG.
yes it says "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Comment: @MichaelButscher
It says maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
and I want it to print all permutations in this way
 PAN AMS CAS NYC HEL

...

PAN CAS AMS NYC HEL

Comment: @DarrylG.
thanks I will check that later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user the itertools module for this.

Basically, when doing permutations and combinations, this is a very useful place.

```py
import itertools

portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]


x = itertools.permutations(portnames)
y = list(x)

# or this is you want to inspect the loop
# y = []
# for i in x:
#     y.append(i)

y
```

The result is a big list:

```
[('PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS')
...
..and so on

('HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS'),
 ('HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS'),
 ('HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN'),
 ('HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS'),
 ('HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN')]
```

As a side note, whilst your attempt was good, because the output is large and the number of recursions is large, you could get stack overflow.

There were two alternative things that you can do:

- increase the limit of recursions
- transform to a `while` or `for` loop.

However, the `itertool.permutations` option is most suitable.

Comment: Instead of the for-loop, it would be faster to do `y = list(x)`

Comment: @Jasmijn yes, i actally only did the for loop becuase was printing out results or may want to do some extra code inside of the loop. But you are completely correct, `list(x)` would be sufficient.

Comment: @D.L.
thanks that is very helpful, but it doesn't completely solve my problem because the course ordered me that task requires a function using recursion. In another meaning I can't change the function called "permutations".

Comment: @Gado,  thank you for clarifying and the kind words. I guess for education purpose you need to know and understand recursion, but at the same time appreciate that there are alternative better methods. The answer above by Mulan is recursion, so compliments this.

Answer (score 2):

We can write `permutations(t)` of any iterable `t` using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if `t` is empty, yield the empty permutation, `()`
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element. For all `p` of the recursive sub-problem `permutations(t[1:])`, for all `i` of `inserts(p, t[0])`, yield `i`

```py
def permutations(t):
  if not t:
    yield ()                       # 1. empty t
  else:
    for p in permutations(t[1:]):  # 2. at least one element
      for i in inserts(p, t[0]):
        yield i
```

Where `inserts(t, x)` can be written using inductive reasoning as well -

1. If the input `t` is empty, yield the final insert, `(x)`
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element. yield `x` prepended to `t` and for all `i` of the recursive sub-problem `inserts(t[1:], x)` yield `t[0]` prepended to `i`

```py
def inserts(t, x):
  if not t:
    yield (x,)                       # 1. empty t
  else:
    yield (x, *t)                    # 2. at least one element
    for i in inserts(t[1:], x):
      yield (t[0], *i)
```

```py
t = ("","","","")
for p in permutations(t):
  print("".join(p))
```

Python has strong support for generators and offers delegation using `yield from ..`. We can simplify the above definitions while maintaining the exact same behaviour -

```py
def permutations(t):
  if not t:
    yield ()
  else:
    for p in permutations(t[1:]):
      yield from inserts(p, t[0])  # <-
```

```py
def inserts(t, x):
  if not t:
    yield (x,)
  else:
    yield (x, *t)
    yield from map(lambda r: (t[0], *r), inserts(t[1:], x)) # <-
```

Generators are a good fit for combinatorics because working with them is natural and straightforward -

```py
# find all permutations where red is left of green
for p in permutations(t):
  if p.index("") < p.index(""):
    print("".join(p))
```

```py
# find all permutations where blue and yellow are adjacent
for p in permutations(t):
  if abs(p.index("") - p.index("")) == 1:
    print("".join(p))
```

Additionally generators can be paused/stopped at any time, allowing us to skip potentially millions of computations for significantly large problems -

```py
# which permutation is in rainbow order?
for (n, p) in enumerate(permutations(t)):
  if p == ("", "", "", ""):
    print(f"permutation {n} is in rainbow order, {p}")
    break  # <- stops generating additional permutations
```

```
permutation 16 is in rainbow order, ('', '', '', '')
```

We use `permutations` with your `portnames` data now -

```py
portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]
for x in permutations(portnames):
  print(x)
```

```py
('PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'HEL')
('CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'HEL')
('AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'HEL')
('NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS')
('NYC', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS')
('NYC', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'NYC')
('CAS', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'AMS')
('CAS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'NYC')
('AMS', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'NYC')
('HEL', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'CAS', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'PAN', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'HEL', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS')
('AMS', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'AMS', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'AMS', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'PAN', 'CAS')
('HEL', 'NYC', 'AMS', 'CAS', 'PAN')
('PAN', 'HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'PAN', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'NYC', 'PAN', 'CAS', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'PAN', 'AMS')
('HEL', 'NYC', 'CAS', 'AMS', 'PAN')
```

Comment: how you did the colored stuff? Nice implementation by the way:)

Comment: python supports unicode strings, so your string can contain all the popupar emoji and symbols